# When do bitcoin miners abandon mining a block?

Tags: bitcoin

Lets say a block 0 has arrived at time t and accepted by all. Then miners with different hashing power start mining on top of block 0.
lets say a miner successfully mined the block 1 at time t+10 min. Then what happens to other miners who are also mining on top of block 0 when they found out that another miner has succesfully mined a block on top of block 0?
Do they stop mining immediately and start mining on Block 1?
Or they wait for some more time before they abandon mining?
Assume all blocks are valid.

Comment: Check out http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com - this is a VFAQ there.

Comment: Short answer is "they stop immediately" - any further effort spent mining on top of 0 is a complete waste of time and energy.